# Dynamic selection field based on another field (Odoo 14)

Tags: python, odoo

Is it possible to populate a selection field dynamically based on another field?
For example:

I have a char field called "A" and a another char field called "B"
I have a selection field called "selection_field"
I want that the selection field automatically will be populated with the choice A and B

This is what i have tried, but it just seems the context wont pass to the function

```
A = fields.Char(string="A Field")
B = fields.Char(string="B Field")
selection_field = fields.Selection(selection=lambda self: self._dynamic_selection() )`

def _dynamic_selection(self):
    select = [(self.A, 'Yes'), (self.B, 'No')]
    records = self
    print("records: ",records)
    return select
```

Result: I get nothing in the select,
and the debug print gives:

```
records:  stock.move.line()
```

so im not getting any record in the function, i don't know what else to do (the model is inherited from stock.move.line but i figured that has nothing to do with this problem)
I would love your help.

Comment: I think more context is needed, I don't think that that's how you pass self as a context. Can you include more code?

Answer (score 1):

Methods used or "created" (lambda) on field definitions are model methods or if you want to call it by the classical name of object-oriented programming: class method. `self` will be an empty recordset. And those methods are called on server (or worker/thread) start and never again.

If you want dynamic selection fields, try to solve that by using `Many2one` fields, which will end by using a model. In views you can either use the `selection` widget on `Many2one` fields, or just make those fields not clickable (option `no_open`) and/or prevent users from adding new entries (option `no_create`).

The "abuse" of the `selection` widget is no longer widespread (looked into Odoo 16), so you probably should use the other option.